# storm topology: one to many (random)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm using the **KafkaSpout** spout to read from all (6) partitions on a kafka topic. The first bolt in the topology has to convert the byte stream into a struct (via IDL definition), lookup a value in a db and pass these values to a second bolt which writes it all into **cassandra**.

There are several issues occurring:

1. Many **fail**(s) from the kafka spout.
2. The first bolt reports "capacity" of > 2.0 from the storm ui.

I've tried to increase the parallelism but it appears that storm will only accept 1:1 from the **kafkaspout** to the first bolt. I'm guessing that #1 is a result of timeouts from the first bolt.

What I want to do: have the kafkaspouts (limited to 1 / kafka partition) able to send their bits to a random first bolt so that I can run many more of these than the # of spouts. The first and second bolts would be 1:1 but the spout to first bolt should be 1:many.

Currently I'm using the **LocalOrShuffleGrouping** to connect between **spout->bolt->bolt**.

---

Edit:

(Re)reading the storms docs I see this passage:

> Shuffle grouping: Tuples are randomly distributed across the bolt's tasks in a way such that each bolt is guaranteed to get an equal number of tuples.

Yet when I look at the load on the executors for my first bolt I see everything concentrated on 6 of them - seemingly *ignoring* the other 24.

I'm missing some large clue here.

Comment: Try using shuffle (not localOrShuffle) right after your spout.  You should have 6 spouts (one per partition), then shuffle, then your bolt.  LocalOrShuffle won't distribute to other workers if there's a local bolt available.

Comment: Can you explain ".. then shuffle.. then your bolt"? I thought 'shuffle' was how the spout would connect to the bolt - not an additional step per se.

Comment: Just use shuffleGrouping() instead of localOrShuffleGrouping(). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ethrbunny Perhaps a code extract so that we can see how things are wired up?